# Get WatchKit interface controller instances created with presentControllerWithNames:contexts:

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm presenting a page based modal using `[self presentControllerWithNames:self.controllerNames contexts:self.controllerContexts];`, where `controllerNames` is just an `NSArray` of `NSString`s containing my interface controllers names. The problem is that I would like to access the created controllers.

The documentations says that

> WatchKit loads and initializes the new interface controllers and animates them into position on top of the current interface controller.

but I would like to have a reference to them, in order to call the `becomeCurrentPage` method from outside.

So, I would like to be able to save those controllers after they are created in a list, and programmatically change the page using something like `[self.controllers[2] becomeCurrentPage]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're allowed to provide a context when you present an interface controller, you can pass a reference to `self`. That way, you can establish a reference from the presented controller to its parent. Once that relationship exists, you can use things like delegation patterns to communicate.

I use this extensively in my own Watch app, and I've wrapped a lot of these mechanics in my [`JBInterfaceController` subclass on GitHub](https://github.com/mikeswanson/JBInterfaceController).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I still don't know how could this work. So, let's say I have a controller named `P`, which opens up a modal containing 2 pages with controllers `A` and `B`. Upon the appearing of the controller `A`, if I press a button inside it, it should be able to call `becomeCurrentPage` on the `B` instance, but `A` only has a reference to `P`, and `B` has a reference to `P`, but `P` doesn't have any reference to `A` nor `B`. So how can I go from `A` _(through `P`)_ to `B`?

Comment: Once `A` or `B` receives a reference to `P`, they can now communicate directly with `P`. That means that they can immediately pass a reference to themselves so that `P` eventually knows about all of its children. This is what happens in the `JBInterfaceController` subclass I referenced. By the way, another method to communicate across controllers is to simply send your own `NSNotification`. This is easier if you don't want to establish and maintain all of these references.